# How can I reset ssh passwords in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, ssh, password, reset, seahorse

I've logged to my home server using ssh from Nautilus. I selected the option "remember forever" (or something similar) after typing my password.
Today I had to change my server's password. Now I can't access it using Nautilus, because the passwords don't match.
I searched in Seahorse expecting to find there Nautilus's stored passwords. But didn't found them.

Anyone knows how to reset Nautilus's passwords?

Comment: The password should be saved as a stored password under default keyring. Also check ~/.ssh/config file and other files in ~/.ssh directory

Comment: No, in Seahorse I don't see it. I have no ~/.ssh/config folder and I suppose it is not in ~/ssh/known_hosts or ~/ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: I'm surprised that Nautilus doesn't offer to re-enter rejected passwords. On another note, I recommend that you don't use (password-based) keyboard authentication for SSH. You should use [public-key authentication](//help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) wherever possible.

Comment: You are right, since nautilus saves them I'm a bit lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `seahorse` utility to manage the passwords. Under the `login` search using the filter for the server name and the right click on the server name to change the password.os

To run the utility type at the command prompt

```
seahorse
```

Comment: Really, it should be there, but it isn't. There I see my facebook and google accounts, one ssh server that is not the server I need and some VPN stuff.

Comment: That's strange. I'd try to move (or delete) the `$HOME/.local/share/keyrings` directory to force nautilus to re-create the password.

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore, I decided to use public-key authentication as suggested by David Foerster. So I cleaned my ~/ssh directory and generated new keys. Now It works.